# 13.04 No sound; sound applet shows Dummy Output

Tags: 13.04, sound, kernel

I upgraded to 13.04 and afterwards the sound wasn’t working. When I look in the sound applet the only device listed is Dummy Output. I have looked online and I tried a couple solutions with no luck. I believe my sound card is being detected by the kernel but it isn't being used.

```
lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: AOPEN Inc. Device 0501
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at d8200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
```

Here are the solutions I have tried:

Solution #1: Didn't work

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
```

Changed RUN=yes to RUN=no

Rebooted

Solution #2: Didn't work

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Reboot

Solution #3: Didn't work

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Reboot

Solution #5: Didn't work and my NIC and mouse stopped working

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic
```

Reboot

**Solution #6: Appears to work**

I had version 3.2.0-51 of the kernel installed from when I ran 12.04, the last time the sound worked, so I rebooted and use grub to selected this version, Now my sound works and the NIC and mouse still work.

Additional Info:
My sound card is an on-board sound card, so the motherboard is an Aopen i915Pa-E R1.00.

```
pulseaudio --check
```

returns nothing

```
pulseaudio --dump-conf
### Read from configuration file: /etc/pulse/daemon.conf ###
daemonize = no
fail = yes
high-priority = yes
nice-level = -11
realtime-scheduling = yes
realtime-priority = 5
allow-module-loading = yes
allow-exit = yes
use-pid-file = yes
system-instance = no
local-server-type = user
cpu-limit = no
enable-shm = yes
flat-volumes = no
lock-memory = no
exit-idle-time = 20
scache-idle-time = 20
dl-search-path = /usr/lib/pulse-3.0/modules
default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa
load-default-script-file = yes
log-target = auto
log-level = notice
resample-method = speex-float-1
enable-remixing = yes
enable-lfe-remixing = no
default-sample-format = s16le
default-sample-rate = 44100
alternate-sample-rate = 48000
default-sample-channels = 2
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right
default-fragments = 8
default-fragment-size-msec = 10
enable-deferred-volume = yes
deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 1
deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0
shm-size-bytes = 0
log-meta = no
log-time = no
log-backtrace = 0
rlimit-fsize = -1
rlimit-data = -1
rlimit-stack = -1
rlimit-core = -1
rlimit-rss = -1
rlimit-as = -1
rlimit-nproc = -1
rlimit-nofile = 256
rlimit-memlock = -1
rlimit-locks = -1
rlimit-sigpending = -1
rlimit-msgqueue = -1
rlimit-nice = 31
rlimit-rtprio = 9
rlimit-rttime = 1000000

amixer -c 0
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 223 [87%] [-6.40dB]
  Front Right: Playback 223 [87%] [-6.40dB]
Simple mixer control 'Beep',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 59 [91%] [24.00dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 59 [91%] [24.00dB] [off]

pacmd dump-volumes
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
Sink 0: reference = 0: 100% 1: 100%, real = 0: 100% 1: 100%, soft = 0: 100% 1: 100%, current_hw = 0: 100% 1: 100%, save = no
Source 0: reference = 0: 100% 1: 100%, real = 0: 100% 1: 100%, soft = 0: 100% 1: 100%, current_hw = 0: 100% 1: 100%, save = no
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you **[edit] your question** and provide more details? Like the Sound Card you are using? The output of `pulseaudio --check`, `pulseaudio --dump-conf`, `amixer -c 0`, `pacmd dump-volumes` and `pactl`.

Comment: I have this same issue. For me, `sudo alsa force-reload` works untill the next reboot. Is this what you mean under 'Solution #2'?

Comment: No, for me none of the solutions I have tried so far have worked at all.